# Galois extension of $ C_{k} $ field and irreducible polynomial over $ C_{k} $ field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, galois-representations, brauer-groups

A field is called a $ C_{k}$- field if every form i.e. every homogeneous polynomial of degree $ d $ in $ n >  d^{k} $ indeterminates has a nontrivial zero. We know that  any finite field is a $ C_{1} $-field. Now for any finite field has a Galois extension of degree
$n$ for every $ n \in \mathbb{N} $  and also there exists an irreducible polynomial $ p(x) $ of degree $n$ for all $ n $ . So can we generalise this over $ C_{m} $  field i.e. my question is

$1.$ Is it true that every $ C_{1} $ field (not $C_{0}$) has a Galois extension of degree $ n $ and admits an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ for all $ n $. Also discuss the case when the field is  $ \mathbb{C}(t) $  because $ \mathbb{C}(t) $  is $ C_{1} $ .

$2$ . Is it true that every $ C_{2} $ field (not $C_{1}$) has a Galois extension of degree $ n $ and admits an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ for all $ n $ .

Comment: Every subfield of the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$ is a quasi-algebraically closed field.  Fix a prime $\ell$.  Consider the subfield of $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$ of all elements whose degree over $\mathbb{F}_p$ is a power of $\ell$. This is a subfield of $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$ that has no field extensions of finite degree equal to a power of $\ell$.

Comment: OK @Jason that means there exist an $C_{1}$ field which has no galois extension  of degree power of l(you mentioned). Can you tell me what's about $\mathbb{C}(t)$ case ?

Comment: @SugataMandal for every $n\ge 1$, $X^n-t$ is irreducible (by the Eisenstein criterion). And its roots generate the field with basis $(t^{k/n})_{0\le k\le n-1}$ over $\mathbf{C}(t)$, which is thus a degree $n$ Galois extension.

Comment: I do not understand your question.  Are you asking about the possible degrees of branched covers of the complex projective line?  Already the morphisms $t\mapsto t^d$ give branched covers of every possible degree.

Comment: @YCor  Sorry, I wrote my comment before I saw your comment.

Comment: Okk @YCor I understand for $C(t)$ now can we say something about $C_{2}$ field ? Especially  when the field is $F(t)$ where $F$ is finite field ?

Comment: What precisely is your question?  The degree-$d$ extensions written by @YCor and myself are defined over $F(t)$, thus give degree-$d$ extensions of those fields.  You can use the same technique as in my answer to give $C_2$-extensions that have no degree-$\ell$ extensions, e.g., for the field $k=GF(p^{\ell^\infty})$ from my comment, consider the Puiseux field $k((t^{1/\ell^\infty}))$.  This is a $C_2$-field with no finite extension of degree $\ell$.

Comment: Yes @Jason Starr, X^n-t is irreducible  over F(t), where F is finite field also thus  we have galois extension,  Can you say  that is this extension  cyclic also? Also Can we say that for any function  field F(x) where F is not algebrically  closed the polynomial  X^n -t is irreducible?